# Como pasar el item de un combobox a una tabla en sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

soy nuevo en visual y tengo un inconveniente al momento de pasar un textbox a una tabla en sql server 2012, lo hace de manera correcta, pero al momento de enviar el contenido que selecciono de un combobox no carga nada en la base de datos, estoy enviando los datos de esta forma:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

comando.CommandText = "insert into equipos (
  placa, fechaDeIngreso, tipoDePc, referencia, tipoDeMntto, 
  estadoFinal, fechaDeSalida, responsable, observaciones ) 
  values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & 
    TextBox4.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & 
    TextBox5.Text & "', '" & TextBox7.Text & "', '" & 
    TextBox8.Text & "', '" & TextBox9.Text & "', '" & 
    TextBox6.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' 
  )"

comando.ExecuteNonQuery()

 End Sub
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        conexion.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-6FH5UOF\SQLEXPRESS2017;Initial Catalog=electronica;Integrated Security=True"
        conexion.Open()
        comando.Connection = conexion

>equiposDT.Columns.Add("Placa")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("fechaDeingreso")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("tipoDePc")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("referencia")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("tipoDeMntto")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("estadoFinal")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("fechaDeSalida")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("responsable")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("observaciones")
        equiposDT.Columns.Add("item")

 End Sub
```

de esa manera tomo los datos de los textbox y el combobox, para ser enviados al sql, ahora al momento de consultar mi base de datos me aparecen todos los valores de los textbox, pero en la columna del combobox me a aparece la palabra NULL, en todas las columnas tengo variables tipo varchar(50). no se porque no guarda el valor.

Gracias, y disculpe la forma en que formule la pregunta.

Comment: Hola. Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Deberías agregar el código que hiciste y probaste. que tiene que ver slqserver en esto? por tabla te refieres a una tabla de la base de datos? aclara todo eso.

Comment: Bienvenido. Debes añadir mas información para que podamos ayudarte. Pulsa en [edit] y pega por ejemplo el código que estas usando, que resultado esperas y que problema tienes actualmente.

Comment: yo leo 9 campos y 10 parametros.. sera un error de la consulta???

Comment: Si, ya quedo solucionada, estaba cometiendo ese error en la consulta.